# wpf application doesnt start

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, windows-7, windows-xp

How do I find out if there is any assembly that I am missing or something else? the application runs fine on my computer (Win 7) but doesn't run on XP, the Process Starts for a few second if I look in Task Manager then Dies? I never see any errors?

Comment: And the EventLog contains ....

Answer (score 1):

We figured out for WPF that we were using an icon file with PNG compression enabled. Apparently, that made our application crash on XP.

Try loading the default icon into your application, and make sure its loaded, then see if it works.